# Show specific categories to logged in users only in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, categories

I want to hide certain categories in my WordPress blog for the public but those that can be viewed by logged in user.

If public goes to visit a restricted category, they should be shown a login box where they must login to view the category

I have the is_user_logged_in function for WordPress but don't know how to use it for this purpose. What should I add to my functions.php?

I have tried this code, but can;t get it to work:

```
  add_action( 'init', 'check_redirect_page' );

function check_redirect_page() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_category( 177 ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/login' ) );
        exit(); 
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions? It just won't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

For second solution to work, replace [**init**] with [**wp**]

New code will be as under:

```
/**
 * Make category members only and redirect non-members to login page.
 */
add_action( 'wp', 'check_redirect_page' );
function check_redirect_page() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_category( 91 ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/wp-admin' ) );
        exit(); 
    }
}
```

Replace **91** with your category ID is and replace **/wp-admin** with  your login for the website.

Answer (score 0):

**I. Category Templates**

You can start building a category template for the category you want to hide:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

E.g. **category-slug.php**

On this page you can then do something like:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ): ?> 
<?php 
    // start The Loop
    // see http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_content();
    // etc.
    ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else:
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/login' ) );
        exit();     
endif; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url

Further I assume you want to have a modal/popup window for the user to login.
For that you can try:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-modal-login/ or
http://wordpress.org/plugins/simplemodal-login/ - though I didn't test those.

For a membership plugin...
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-members/ can you be your friend.

**II. Or you can try (the simple way):**

```
<?php 
add_action( 'init', 'check_redirect_page' );

function check_redirect_page() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_category( 177 ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/login' ) );
        exit(); 
    }
}
?>
```

As you said this code should reside in your functions.php.

Comment: I prefer the functions.php solution but that code says that IF user is logged in then re-direct BUT I want it to be the other way round. So if user is logged in, show it but if they are not then redirect

Comment: No, it says if ( !is_user_logged_in() ... Note the ! - it returns true if the user is not logged in. :)

Comment: Thank you, let me give this a shot

Comment: This code didn't seem to work for me. I used it without the php tags, is that correct?